# Drawing blocks for a 2D game background

Tags: java, game, graphics

This draws blocks on the screen from a grid to make a background for my game. I am wondering if anyone has any suggestions on optimizing it for speed.

```
int blockwidth=blocksize-2;
//Draw coloured blocks
for (int x=0;x<sizex;x++){
   int screenx=-(int)camerax+(x*blocksize);
      if (screenx>-blocksize && screenx<gamewidth){
        for (int y=0;y<sizey;y++){
          int screeny=-(int)cameray+(y*blocksize);    
          if (screeny>-blocksize && screeny<gameheight){              
            if (tiles[x][y][0]>0){
                g.setColor(new Color( tiles[x][y][1]));
                //g.fillRect(screenx,screeny,blockwidth,blockwidth); 
                g.drawImage(Iloader.Imagelist.get(0), screenx,screeny, screenx+blockwidth,screeny+blockwidth, graphicsize,0,graphicsize*2,graphicsize, null);
            } else {
                //g.setColor(new Color( tiles[x][y][1]  | 0xFFFF0000));
                g.setColor(new Color( tiles[x][y][1]));
                g.fillRect(screenx,screeny,blockwidth,blockwidth);   

            }
          }
        }
    }
 }
```

Comment: In which method is this? I assume `paintComponent` or similar? Have you checked how often that method is called? How often does the tiles actually change?

Comment: I include it in my render method so every frame update

Comment: Therefore I could pop it in another method to copy to an offscreen image and only call it if it changes BUT have the render method copy the whole other image each frame update.

Comment: How often does the value of a specific `tiles[x][y][1]` or `tiles[x][y][0]` change?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few optimizations I can see in your code.

1. creating a new Color every time is a little severe. You can do a few things here, for example, if your color palette is limited, then cache the individual Color instances. I know it sounds petty right now, but, when you add it up there are a lot of new Color instances created.

   What you should at minimum do, is track your last Color used, and only create a new one if it is different.
2. Pull the `Iloader.Imagelist.get(0)` outside the loop, and have `Image image = Iloader.Imagelist.get(0)`
3. Pull calculations outside the loops where you can... and continue/break when you can too.

   ```
   Image image = Iloader.Imagelist.get(0);
   int screenx=-(int)camerax - blocksize;
   for (int x = 0; x < sizex; x++){
       screenx += blocksize;
       if (screenx <= -blocksize) {
           continue;
       }
       if (screenx >= gamewidth) {
           break;
       }
       int screeny= -(int)cameray - blocksize;
       for (int y = 0; y < sizey; y++){
           screeny += blocksize;
           if (screeny <= -blocksize)
               continue;
           }
           if (screeny >= gameheight) {
               break;
           }              
           if (tiles[x][y][0] > 0) {
               // need to set the color here? g.setColor(new Color( tiles[x][y][1]));
               g.drawImage(image, screenx, screeny, screenx + blockwidth,
                           screeny + blockwidth, graphicsize, 0, graphicsize * 2,
                           graphicsize, null);
           } else {
                   //g.setColor(new Color( tiles[x][y][1]  | 0xFFFF0000));
               g.setColor(new Color( tiles[x][y][1]));
               g.fillRect(screenx,screeny,blockwidth,blockwidth);   

           }
       }
   }
   ```

The above code does not have the mechanism for caching the color. You should figure one out.

Comment: Thanks, will try ALL of that; I have not come across using continue break in this way either so you have taught me something significant.